# Write down all the topologies on $\{a,b\}$ consisting of two points

Tags: general-topology

Perhaps it's only the language here...what is meant by "two points"?
I mean, if it means "two elements only" then, well, isn't that just the indiscrete topology?

> $\tau=\{\{a,b\},\phi\}$

I mean, otherwise, say $\{\{a,b\},\phi.\{a\}\}$ or anything else possible would have more than two. And this is a $4$ mark question in the pat papers so I'm guessing it shouldn't be as easy as I think that it's only the indiscrete topology.

Anyone know what is meant?

Comment: I think what's meant was probably "Write down all the topologies on the 2-point set $\{a,b\}$."

Comment: oh, you're right, it can be interpreted that way, that was silly...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you list all subsets of $\{\{a,b\},\{a\},\{b\},\varnothing\}$?

If so, then you just can just go through and pick the ones that form a topology (many will be disqualified immediately for not containing $\{a,b\}$ or $\varnothing$).